# PyTorch: count the number of tensor values that are near (+/- a tolerance) the values of a reference tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have 2 tensors of an arbitrary shape with several dimensions.

- target_tensor
- predicted_tensor

I want to count the number of values in the predicted_tensor that are near to the values of the target tensor.

With a for loop it shall be something like this:

```py
targets = torch.flatten(target_tensor)
predicted = torch.flatten(predicted_tensor)

correct_values = 0
tolerance = 0.1

for i, prediction in enumerate(predicted):
    target = targets[i]
    if (target - tolerance < prediction < target + tolerance):
        correct_values =+ 1
```

However, a for loop is not a really good idea for performances.

I'm looking for a vectorized solution. I tried :

```py
torch.sum(target - tolerance < prediction < target + tolerance)
```

But I got:

```s
RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

In Julia it would be just adding a dot to precise that it is element wise.

Any idea on how to implement that with PyTorch with a short vectorized solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`torch.isclose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.10/generated/torch.isclose.html):

```py
correct_values = torch.isclose(prediction, target, atol=tolerance, rtol=0).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is pretty straightforward's with this helper function.